# Union in big query

Tags: google-bigquery, union-all

Can I ask how to write the correct query for UNION in Big Query.

For example,
Table A = has some columns which the data type is not string.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqwUC.png)

Table B = No such columns in the picture above.

Can someone help to write the correct query

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying `null` values:

```
with table_a as (
  select 'from table a' as src, current_datetime() as datetime_column, 1.5 as float_column, 3 as integer_column
),
table_b as (
  select 'from table b' as src
)
select * from table_a
union all
select src, null, null, null from table_b
```

[image]